# MySQL error 1136, why can I not add these entries to my table

Tags: mysql

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71viH.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4unfW.png)

I don't know why I keep getting an error

Thank you in advance

Comment: Depending on the SQL_MODE, `0000-00-00` may be an invalid date.

Comment: Please do not post your code as links to screenshot images. Just use text for code. This is covered in the Stack Overflow guide on [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I recommend you read the articles in the Help Center to get the best experience you can out of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INSERT syntax allows inserting multiple rows, but each row needs to be in its own tuple:

```
insert into shoppinglistTest(itemdescription, quantity, dateadded)
values
('Bananas',20,'0000-00-00'),
('apples',10,'0000-00-00'),
('grapes',20,'0000-00-00'),
('gatorade',10,'0000-00-00'),
('steak',10,'0000-00-00'),
('milk',2,'0000-00-00'),
('eggs',4,'0000-00-00');
```

The syntax you tried to use used a single tuple of 21 values for a column list of 3 columns. The number of columns in your column list must be the same as the number of values in *each* tuple in the VALUES clause. But you can make a list of many tuples.

Comment: Thank you so much!!